# merge dicts with overlapping keys

Tags: python

I'm looking to make a GeoJSON to return by combining 3 other GeoJSON dict objects. The three entries have the same keys but different values. For example like this

```
d1 = {"type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [102.0, 0.5]
      },
      "properties": {
        "prop0": "value0"
      }
    }
d2 = {"type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [102.0, 0.0], [103.0, 1.0], [104.0, 0.0], [105.0, 1.0]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "prop0": "value0",
        "prop1": 0.0
      }
    }
d3 =  {"type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0],
            [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "prop0": "value0",
        "prop1": { "this": "that" }
      }
    }
```

The desired output is like this

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [102.0, 0.5]
      },
      "properties": {
        "prop0": "value0"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [102.0, 0.0], [103.0, 1.0], [104.0, 0.0], [105.0, 1.0]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "prop0": "value0",
        "prop1": 0.0
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0],
            [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "prop0": "value0",
        "prop1": { "this": "that" }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

When I try to use methods like `out.update(d1), out.update(d2)` the keys overlap so all 3 dictionaries aren't appended.

Comment: hi, what is the desired output?

Comment: How is your desired output related to the input? Where are the keys `key1` and `key2`?

Comment: Can you show what your desired output would be from your example?

Comment: `update()` won't automatically combine values into a list. When there are duplicate keys, it just replaces it.

Comment: @Barmar edited question so the example matches the desired output. Yes when there are duplicate keys it replaces the value. but I want to have all values for the matched keys still shown

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I merge two dictionaries in a single expression (taking union of dictionaries)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-taking-union-of-dictiona)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've deleted my previous answer as I misunderstood your question. After the edit you've made I am now clear what you really expected is nothing but combining the dicts as a list. So the code with this three dicts will be nothing but:

```
dd = defaultdict(list)

featureNode = [d1,d2,d3]

dd['features'] = featureNode
dd['type'] = "FeatureCollection"

print(dd)
```

And you'll get your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

`update` doesn't look at values at all; it's only concerned with merge the keys sets. If you want to merge the *values* of existing keys, you need to do that yourself.

For example, you might want to consolidate the values in a list:

```
merged = {}
for d in [d1, d2, d3]:
    for key in d:
        merged.setdefault(key, []).append(d[key])
```

or you might want to sum the values:

```
merged = defaultdict(int)
for d in [d1, d2, d3]:
    for key in d:
        merged[key] += d[key]
```

etc. In general, you could define a function that takes a combining function:

```
from operator import add

def accumulate(x, y):
    if isinstance(x, list):
        return x + [y]
    else:
        return [x, y]

def merge(f, *dicts):
    m = {}
    for d in dicts:
        for key in d:
            if key not in m:
                m[key] = d[key]
            else:
                m[key] = f(m[key], d[key])
    return m

merged1 = merge(accumulate, d1, d2, d3)
merged2 = merge(operator.add, d1, d2, d3)
```

You can see how this can get more complicated if you need different combining functions for each key, so it should not be surprising that there is not a single, built-in way to merge dicts by value.